# In the Godfather, where did they drive to with Carlo's feet sticking out of the front window after he was killed?

Tags: the-godfather

The Corleone compound did not seem to be that large so it seems that they would have been driving down the street at that point.

Answer (score 2):

### We don't know

In neither the movie or the original novel are we told how Carlo's body was disposed of.

It didn't just disappear, as Connie accuses Michael of having Carlo killed, so presumably it was taken to a funeral parlor for proper burial (perhaps Bonasera did the family another favor) but that is just supposition.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking how they could be seen to drive so far without going outside the mall, at which point surely they'd risk Carlo's feet being seen sticking out of the car's windscreen.

Actually, it's a pretty short drive they make and it's all comfortably inside the mall. The camera is put on the car bonnet so you can see the background through the side/rear windows.

Start a clock when the garrotte goes around Carlo's neck. At 7 seconds, they start driving. At 18 seconds, Carlo finally stops moving. At 20 seconds, we cut so the car journey could end any time from then.

When you look through the windows, they really don't travel far up the mall. Unfittingly, the engine noise sound effects used are of a car travelling along faster than what that car actually does.